# Kiosk-mode in OS X: fullscreen doesn't work at startup

Tags: macos, fullscreen, kiosk-mode

in order to have an application that automatically opens in fullscreen as soon as the user logs in, I'm trying to open it in kiosk mode so that the user cannot close it or do any other operation than using this app.

With the following code in the AppDelegate it only works when I launch the application manually, but **it does not open in fullscreen when the application is automatically opened at startup** (I've added it in System Preferences, Accounts, Login items):

```
-(void) awakeFromNib {
    NSApplicationPresentationOptions presentationOptions = (NSApplicationPresentationHideDock |
                                                            NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar |
                                                            NSApplicationPresentationDisableAppleMenu |
                                                            NSApplicationPresentationDisableProcessSwitching |
                                                            NSApplicationPresentationDisableForceQuit |
                                                            NSApplicationPresentationDisableSessionTermination |
                                                            NSApplicationPresentationDisableHideApplication);
    NSDictionary *fullScreenOptions = @{NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions: @(presentationOptions)};
    [_window.contentView enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:fullScreenOptions];
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling toggleFullScreen of NSWindow and have constraints for its views to grow in size relative to the NSWindow

Answer (score 0):

Your app is probably not the active app.  An app's presentation options only take effect when it's active.

You probably need to do `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]` before entering full-screen.